# How to boot to BIOS - IBM System X3400 M3

Tags: ibm, bios

I need help to boot to BIOS for my IBM System X3400 M3. What I know is pressing F12 to boot to BIOS. But every time I presses F12 it never go to BIOS. Instead it boots to my ESXi. UEFI is very slow.

What do I do wrong here? I need to change the boot sequence to boot from CD to upgrade my ESXi server.

Comment: Hi All, I am still unable to upgrade my ESXi to 5.5 Update for my System X3400 M3. I have followed the instructions; shutdown the server, turn it back ON, press F12. And it still boots to my old ESXi 4.1. Could you please tell me when is the right time to press F12 during the boots. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IBM keeps the functionality across xSeries servers pretty consistent, and the x3400 is no different.  From the manual:

> The Boot Menu program is a built-in, menu-driven configuration program
> that you can use to temporarily redefine the first startup device
> without changing settings in the Configuration/Setup Utility program.
>
> To use the Boot Menu program, complete the following steps:
>
> 1. Turn off the server.
> 2. Restart the server.
> 3. Press F12.
> 4. Select the startup device.
>
> The next time the server is started, it returns to the startup
> sequence that is set in the Configuration/Setup Utility program

If hitting F12 isn't working, you are either not pressing it at the right time (watch the screen, or just every 2 seconds tap it once while it boots) or something has gone really wrong in which case a call to IBM support is in order.

Comment: Hi TheCleaner, thank you for your help. I have scheduled this Friday to do ESXi upgrade. Will do your suggestion and let you know the outcome. Thank you.